# Sorting files in a folder into subfolders with a specific/maximum number of files

Tags: windows-7

Im a bit of a noob on programming so i need some help. Im using windows 7 BTW

i have several folders ; 0,A,B,C,D etc. each contains somewhere between 150 and 8000 files that start with the same letter as the folder they are in( so they are sorted). the problem is, that the piece of software i need to use these files on only displays up to 254 files per folder. So what i need, is a way to sort these files in the folders into subfolders with max 254 files in each. So the result will be something like this:

A:\
   A1(256 files)
   A2(256 files)
   A3(256 files)
   A4(120 files)

Answer (score 1):

With c# use something like this should get you started:

```
  string[] saFilelist = Directory.GetFiles(@"A:\A");
  int iNumOfFoldersToCreate = saFilelist.Length/256;
    for(int i = 0; i<iNumOfFoldersToCreate ; i++)
    {
        string sCurrentDir = @"A:\A" + i.ToString();
        Directory.CreateDirectory(sCurrentDir );
        for(int j = 0; j<256 ; j++)
        {

            File.Move(saFilelist[i*256+j], sCurrentDir + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(saFilelist[i*256+j])); 

        }
    }
```

Comment: is it possible to do in other ways? i dont own c# and have no idea how to use it? :-)

Comment: You can download a free version of c# from here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=40787